# Gauss identities of $q$-analog

Tags: combinatorics, q-analogs

How can we use the Jacobi-Triple Product Identity to show that in the area of q-analog series and theory:

**Jacobi- Triple Product Identity:**
$$\sum_{{n\in\mathbb{Z}}}x^nq^{n^2}=\prod_{k \ge 1}(1-q^{2k})(1+xq^{2k-1})(1-x^{-1}q^{2k-1})$$

Now how to use the above to show that:

$$\prod_{k\ge1}\frac{1-q^k}{1+q^k}=\sum_{{n\in\mathbb{Z}}}(-1)^nq^{n^2}$$
$$\prod_{k\ge1}\frac{1-q^{2k}}{1-q^{2k-1}}=\sum_{n\ge0}q^{\binom{n+1}{2}}$$

I can prove the Jacobi triple product identity, but I have alittle trouble using suitable manipulations to show the following two identities from the Jacobi's identity. I would appreciate the help offered.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put $x=-1$ and $x=q$ into these equations. Look at the second.
$$\sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty q^{n^2+n}=\prod_{k=1}^\infty(1-q^{2k})
(1+q^{2k})(1+q^{2k-2}).$$
Divide by $2$ and replace $q^2$ by $q$:
$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty q^{(n^2+n)/2}=\prod_{k=1}^\infty(1-q^{k})(1+q^{k})^2
=\prod_{k=1}^\infty\frac{(1-q^{2k})^2}{1-q^k}.$$
Then $\prod_{k=1}^\infty(1-q^k)=\prod_{k=1}^\infty(1-q^{2k-1})
\prod_{k=1}^\infty(1-q^{2k})$. Using this will simplify the product
to your form.

Comment: Thank you this was very neat.